# Move camera after ctrl alt Numpad 0

Tags: camera

I've seen tutorials about setting the camera view with ctrl alt Numpad 0 but many times, after setting the camera and while still in Camera Set View mode some are still able to adjust the camera position. If i click MB it gets me out of Camera Set View mode. How do i do that?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to select the camera (you will see the yellow selection on the border) and use <kbd>G</kbd>  to move or <kbd>R</kbd>  to rotate the camera.

another option is to lock the camera view by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>  on the viewport to open the sidebar> View > Lock Camera to view